# PHP não faz consulta ao banco de dados com o rowCount()

Tags: php, mysql

Bom pessoal estou fazendo um sistema de Login, mas acredito eu, estou com um problema com a conexão com o banco de dados, porque só retorna o valor false, sendo que o true envolve uma consulta com o BD... abaixo segue o cód.:

Essa é a conexão com o Banco de Dados:

```
<?php
function __autoload($class){require_once"{$class}.class.php";}

abstract class ConDB{
    private $cnx;
    private function setConn(){
        return
        is_null($this->cnx)?
                $this->cnx=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=silkgra','admin','admin'):
                $this->cnx;
    }

    public function getConn(){
        return $this->setConn();
    }
}

    $lgn=new Login;
    var_dump($lgn->setLogin('teste@teste.com','12345678'));
```

?>

Esse é o cód. do Login:

```
<?php
class Login{
    private $vem,$vsh,$cpt,$crud,$email,$senha,$log,$dds;
    public function setLogin($email,$senha){
        $this->vem=new ValidaEmail;
        $this->vsh=new ValidaSenha;
        $this->cpt=new Cripto;
        $this->crud=new CRUD;

        $this->email=$this->vem->setValidaEmail($email);
        $this->senha=$this->vsh->setValidaSenha($senha);

        $this->log=$this->senha==$senha?
                    $this->crud->select('idUsuario','usuario','WHERE email=? && senha=?',
                    array($this->email,$this->cpt->setCripto($this->senha))):
                    FALSE;

        return $this->log->rowCount();

        if($this->log && $this->log->rowCount()>0){
            foreach($this->log as $this->dds){
                $_SESSION['logado']=$this->dds;
                return true;
                //header('location:../../admin/');
            }
        } else {
            return 'Acesso Negado...';
        }
    }
}
```

?>

ESTE É O PRINT DO BANCO DE DADOS:
[image: ESTE É O PRINT DO BANCO DE DADOS]

acontece q quando uso dados q ja estão no banco de dados não retorna nada, mas eu tenho esses dados armazenados

quando eu vou fazer o teste aparece o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function rowCount() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\silkgra\require\class\Login.class.php on line 18

Ae rray da uma olhada, esse é o arquivo CRUD que fiz para fazer a conexão:

```
<?php
class CRUD extends ConDB{
    private $query;
    private function prepExec($prep,$exec){
        $this->query=$this->getConn()->prepare($prep);
        $this->query->execute($exec);
        if(!$pdo->execute()){ print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); die('deu ruim');}
    }

    public function insert($table,$cond,$exec){ // o $cond aqui remete a condição
        $this->prepExec('INSERT INTO '.$table.' SET '.$cond.'',$exec);
        return $this->getConn()->lastInsertId();
    }

    public function select($fields,$table,$cond,$exec){
        $this->prepExec('SELECT '.$fields.' FROM '.$table.' '.$cond.'',$exec);
        return $this->query;
    }

    public function update($table,$cond,$exec){
        $this->prepExec('UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$cond.'',$exec);
    }

    public function delete($table,$cond,$exec){
        $this->prepExec('DELETE FROM '.$table.' '.$cond.'',$exec);
    }

}
```

?>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ai rray, retornou isso mano

Comment: vc precisa o que dentro de `$this->crud->select()` imagino que tenha um `execute()` do PDO, ele deve estar falhando, pode ver o erro (se ele existir) assim: `if(!$pdo->execute()){ print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); die('deu ruim');}` lembre de trocar `$pdo` pela sua variável que recebe o `prepare()`

Comment: ae rray essa linha de cód. em qual parte do cód. eu coloco? desculpa as muitas perguntas mano, mais acontece q eu estou começando a estudar php e mysql agr, tendeu.. desculpa msm

Comment: Faz o teste no método `prepExec()`

Comment: ae rray atualizei lá mano deu 2 msg